# Google Chrome not rendering Latex in browser

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

I have seen a solution to this problem for Firefox, but assume it is not the same for Chrome. This just started happening recently, and I have no idea how to fix it! Any mathematical typesetting on any website is no longer working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: with me Tex in Google Chrome works well, I have never encountered this kind of problem. I suppose MO uses MathJax for Tex rendering, does not it?

Comment: clearing browser data might solve the problem: chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

Comment: What version / build of chrome and OS? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Google Chrome v. 29.0.1547.66 m. Windows 7 and Windows Vista (both my Laptop and Desktop do not work). IE also does not work.

I tried re-installing Google Chrome, but no luck!

Comment: What happens when you click [this link](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML)? It points to the mathjax CDN, which is what renders TeX on the browser. If your network is blocking it, TeX won't work.

Comment: It turns out it was Rogers and Cisco that was the problem. They had some strange DNS thingy going on. It was just fixed today! Hooray! Thanks to everyone for their comments, I appreciate your time!